# How to send FCM tokens to multiple devices using tokens in API v1?

Tags: .net, flutter, rest, firebase-cloud-messaging

It is possible to send a push notification using Firebase using REST APIs to a set of devices using the corresponding token?
I know that in the past, using the deprecated APIs, it was possible to send a multicast request to an array of tokens, possibility that I cannot find anymore using v1 APIs. There was also the possibility to create devices groups, but I cannot find the updated documentation about that.

In my use case, I save in a database the FCM tokens of my clients and I would like to send personalized push notifications to a subset of them, for example, to the ones having an appointment with my shop in the following day.
Topics subscription do not seem a working alternative for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed no HTTP API to multi-cast messages anymore. You will have to call the v1 API for each message to send, but this typically happens over a long-lived connection under the hood - in which case the overhead is not that large.

If you'd like to see an example of how to perform sends to multiple client, I recommend looking up the code for the newer multi-send messages in the **Admin SDK** of your choice, as those do precisely that.